# Delphi ADOStoredProcedure calling a procedure with OUT params and capturing them after the call

Tags: mysql, delphi, stored-procedures, parameters

I am wanting to use an ADOStoredProcedure object to call a stored procedure from a database

The stored procedure returns 3 varchar(255)'s : `Processed`, `record_set_size` and `records_remaining`

I then want to capture the returned values into a variable on delphi's side 
I am currently using MySQL and Delphi 7

The stored procedure works fine on its own in MySQL so theres nothing the fault on that side.

At the moment the code in delphi is:

```
ADOWizconSP.ProcedureName := 'proc_moveToWizconTemp';
ADOWizconSP.Parameters.Refresh;

ADOWizconSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@processed').Value := processed;
ADOWizconSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@record_set_size').Value := record_set_size;
ADOWizconSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@records_remaining').Value := records_remaining;
ADOWizconSP.ExecProc;
          lb_wizconValues.Items.Add(IntToStr(ADOWizconSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@processed').Value));
          lb_wizconValues.Items.Add(IntToStr(ADOWizconSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@record_set_size').Value));
          lb_wizconValues.Items.Add(IntToStr(ADOWizconSP.Parameters.ParamByName('@records_remaining').Value));
```

I am presented with the error:

```
ADOWizconSP: 'Parameter @processed@not found'
```

Can anyone help me with what I am trying to achieve here.

Kind Regards,

Jordan :)

Comment: Delphi parameters don't use `@`, so remove them.

Comment: Rookie Mistake :) However i am getting another issue :(

it is saying: 

[Mysql][odbc 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.0.41-community-nt]OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine taglogging.proc_moveToWizconTemp is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger.

The procedure takes no parameters but returns 3, i dont know how to capture the 3 returned parameters :( @KenWhite

Comment: I have no idea, because all I know of your procedure and it's parameters is what you've posted here in your question. There's no way for me to know anything more.

Comment: So if your parameters are output, why are you trying to assign them values ? You've called `Refresh` which should determine the parameter types (if they are input, output or both). Simply call `ExecProc` and take what your procedure return after.

Comment: Im trying to capture them in variables on the delphi side once the stored procedure is ran. Once ran it completes a task and returns 3 varchar values. i want to capture each one of these values in separate variables on the delphi side :)
I'm new to stored procedures and the ADO of delphi so I'm aware i might have made mistakes :). I put them in to try and create a sort of relationship hoping that the delphi would recognize the null variables going in and then when they are returned, assign them when it comes out. If that makes sense.

Comment: You are not capturing them anyhow (in the 3 lines before `ExecProc` method call). You are trying to set them values. And if they are output, which the `Refresh` most probably detected, you've ended up with an error for attempt to storing values to output parameters. Remove those 3 lines before `ExecProc` and remove `@` chars from the parameter names in the following 3 lines and I think you should be fine. You could do what you are doing if your params would be in/out.