# Delphi Stored Procedure Output

Tags: mysql, delphi, stored-procedures, output

Can anyone help me capture an output variable from a stored procedure in a delphi variable please?
I've look at other questions here and had little success implementing

At the moment I have a stored procedure:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `return_10`(out x varchar(5))
BEGIN
  SET x = 10;

END
```

As you can see it is a very basic procedure.

In delphi I want to call this procedure and capture the output variable and have tried the following but I have a feeling its wrong.

Implementation:

```pascal
var
  stored_proc: TADOStoredProc;

(* GETTING A RETURN VALUE FROM A STORED PROCEDURE *)

stored_proc.ProcedureName := 'return_10';
stored_proc.Parameters.Clear;
stored_proc.Parameters.CreateParameter( '@RETURN_VALUE', ftInteger, pdReturnValue, 10, null);
stored_proc.ExecProc;
lbl_connected.Caption := stored_proc.Parameters.ParamByName( '@RETURN_VALUE' ).Value
```

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: Remove the `@` in both your parameter statements. Delphi doesn't use them.

Comment: [`Déjà vu`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26489266/960757)

Comment: Didn't we go over this [last time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26489266)?

Comment: Hi Ken, I tried to understand last time but speaking to my manager i wasn't allowed to change it to an input rather than an out unfortunately and looking at the examples i couldn't get my head around it i'm afraid.I did appreciate your help though; it cleared up a few things )

Answer (score 1):

As a general advice you might place a TAdoStoredProc on your Form/Datamodule, assign the property `ProcedureName` and inspect the parameters.
Another way might be adding a debug output for the parameters.

Since I'm not capable of MySQL, I can only display the result of a SQL-Server procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE return_10(@x varchar(5) OUT)
AS
BEGIN
    Set @x=10;
    Return 1;
END
```

The parameters shown from DebugParams are here:

```
@RETURN_VALUE
@x
```

where @RETURN_VALUE would be an value used for status or ID's
and @x would by our parameter of the procedure exactly named as in the procedure declaration.

You don't have to add or create any parameters, just call `Refresh` after assigning `ProcedureName`
and adapt the `Direction` which might not be set correct.

```pascal
Procedure DebugParams(ads:TAdoStoredProc);
Var
 I:Integer;
 sl:TStringList;
begin
       sl:=TStringList.Create;
       try
       for I := 0 to ads.Parameters.Count - 1 do
        begin
          sl.Add(ads.Parameters[i].Name);
        end;
       Showmessage(sl.Text);
       finally
         sl.Free;
       end;
end;

procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin    
    stored_proc.ProcedureName := 'return_10';
    stored_proc.Parameters.Clear;
    stored_proc.Parameters.Refresh;
    DebugParams(stored_proc);
    stored_proc.Parameters.ParamByName('@x').Direction := pdOutput;
    stored_proc.ExecProc;
    Caption := stored_proc.Parameters.ParamByName('@x').Value;
end;
```